# What to do if you are interested in a (good) question that didn't get a good answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, old-questions

Today I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202198/whats-the-best-manner-of-implementing-a-social-activity-stream) Stack Overflow question while Googling. I wanted to reopen the conversation and try to ask about scalable solutions (the solutions posed are not) but the question is eight months old and basically dead.

I guess the best thing to do would be to ask again? This got me wondering about dead questions that have some answers but could be expanded upon. Are redundant questions with good answers spread among them a bad thing? Certain other sites that SO competes with have this problem in a big way and it can be frustrating when turning up pages in Google.

Is there some other "right" way of re-starting a conversation that died because the asker was satisfied or absent?

Comment: The ties in to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/cleaning-up-our-rubbish-do-we-have-a-responsability-to-clean-up-old-questions

Comment: Tha tie-in and the comments are interesting - in this case, answers would (hopefully) be made obsolete by a new question but answers made obsolete by time are also an issue.

Answer (score 6):

**Why not research and add an answer to the question yourself?** This will bump it to the front page and engender discussion. You can also edit your answer over time to improve it, which will also bump the question. (Note that trivial editing for the sake of bumping alone is considered abuse and seriously frowned upon. Not that you'd do this, but just putting the disclaimer in..)

**If you feel the question failed because it was asked in a flawed way, edit it to improve the question.** This will also bump the question and maybe result in new answers and interest.
If you don't have the 2k rep to edit someone else's question and you feel the question was flawed, [suggest an edit to that question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Comment: +1 - you only forgot: gaining Necromancer badge...

Answer (score 3):

If possible, I would rephrase your question to be sufficiently different to the original and include a link to the original. If its too close it'll get closed as a duplicate. Only the owner used to be able to really reignite a question (by starting a bounty on it); [**anyone can do this since June 2010**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) so that would be an option in this situation.

If that's not possible, well, perhaps you should post the link to the question here and what your question is as well as how the existing answers are insufficient and perhaps we can give specific advice.