# Old questions without accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, support, unanswered-questions, accept-rate, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do about old orphaned questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-to-do-about-old-orphaned-questions)

Hi all.

I constantly stumble upon old questions that have multiple plausible answers but the user that formerly asked them never accepted any. Is there a way to accept an answer after taking the time to test each suggestion?

I'm aware that the reputation incentive is there to prevent this from happening, but is there a way to take ownership of someone else's old unattended question without asking the same again (Orphan Question Adoption Program)?

Answer (score 2):

You could post a bounty and then award it to an answer you feel is most deserving.

There is no way to force a user to accept an answer.

Comment: Nor is there any *need* to force an acceptance. Getting an answer accepted is not some magic event that fulfills anyone's destiny or makes all well with the world.